# C++ cast vector template

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-cast

I want to cast BaseClass to DerivedClass std vector using a template:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
vector<U> CastTo<U>(vector<T> &input)
{
    vector<U> output;
    for (auto obj : input)
    {
        output.push_back(dynamic_cast<U>(obj));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Is this possible?

Right now the template is not being recognized and I not able to use it. Is there a mistake in the proposed way?

The usage is:

```
vector<BaseClass*> vec;
vector<DerivedClass*> dVec = CastTo<DerivedClass*>(vec);
```

Comment: [mcve], please. Nothing stands out as overly wrong in your snippet.

Comment: What do you mean by "the template is not being recognized"? Do you get build errors? Then please show us the errors (copy-pasted, in full and complete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things,

1. don't use the `<U>` in the definition of `CastTo<U>`,
2. swap the order of `T` and `U` in the `template` line.

The first is just how the syntax for function templates goes in C++: no template brackets after their name. (But you will need one when calling the function.)

The second is more tricky. If you had a `template<typename T, typename U>` function and called `CastTo<DerivedClass*>(vec)`, then `DerivedClass*` would be matched to the first parameter, `T`, leaving no way of determining `U`:

```
CastTo<DerivedClass*, ???>(vec): vector<DerivedClass*> &input -> ???
       ===== T =====  =U=                ↑ T

> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U’
```

If it's `template<typename U, typename T>`, then `U` will be `DerivedClass*` and `T` can be found from the function's argument `vec`:

```
1. CastTo<DerivedClass*, ???>(vec): vector<???> &input -> vector<DerivedClass*>
          ===== U =====  =T=                     ↑ vec            ↑ U
2. vec is a vector<BaseClass*>  =>  T = BaseClass*

> OK
```

This works (minimal example using primitive types and a C-style cast):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename U, typename T>
vector<U> CastTo(vector<T> &input)
{
    vector<U> output;
    for (auto obj : input)
    {
        output.push_back(U(obj));
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
  vector<float> v{2,3,5};
  vector<int> w = CastTo<int>(v);
  return w[2];  // returns 5
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
template<typename T, typename U>
vector<U> CastTo<U>(vector<T> &input)
                ^^^
```

Remove that `<U>` (why the ALL_UPPERCASE that's for macros?). Also, be aware that your example call might be confusing `T` and `U`.

Comment: Good spot on that. Tricky brackets

Comment: Okey, but how it is possible to specify the desired derived class? I naïvely wrote resembling what I am used to (C#)

Comment: @Sturm `CastTo<DerivedClass*>` still specifies the first template parameter. There is no extra `<U>` in the definition, which is a different syntax to C#

Comment: I'm aware of that, @Caleth, hence the last remark. Since the OP doesn't provide an MCVE, I'm not going to do all their work though.